# Click coordinates on canvas no longer match mouse after keydown simulated click

Tags: javascript, canvas

I’m using the `keydown` event to simulate clicks on a canvas. The click coordinates I’m using are `window.innerWidth / 2` for x and 100 for y, which lie within the canvas. Then the click coordinates relative to the canvas are the red shaded area’s x-position + 1 and y-position + 1. This is the case as long as the `keyDown` variable is set to `true` on the `keydown` event. Otherwise, it’ll be the mouse click coordinates minus the canvas offsets. Therefore, an alert should say that the click was inside the shaded area every time I press the spacebar and only then.

The problem is that if I use the mouse to click an area after using the spacebar, the alert will keep showing the same coordinates as if I used the spacebar again. If I use the mouse after page load and before my first spacebar use, the alert will show the correct coordinates.

In other words, if I mouse-clicked (40, 39) and (170, 173), alerts will tell me that those areas were inside and outside the shaded area respectively. If I used the spacebar to simulate a chosen click at (26, 21) and then use the mouse again, the alert will keep giving me (26, 21). How I fix that?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0],
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    keyDown = false,
    areaX = 25,
    areaY = 20,
    areaW = 100,
    areaH = 100,
    event = "ontouchstart" in document.documentElement ? "touchstart" : "click";

// shaded area
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(192,0,0)";
ctx.fillRect(areaX, areaY, areaW, areaH);

function userAction(e, x, y, w, h, isKey) {
  var cnv = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0],
      clickX = e.pageX - cnv.offsetLeft,
      clickY = e.pageY - cnv.offsetTop;
   
  if (isKey == true) {
    // simulate click somwhere in area
    clickX = x + 1;
    clickY = y + 1;
  }
  
  if (clickX > x && clickX < x + w && clickY > y && clickY < y + h) {
      alert("Inside shaded area at (" + clickX + ", " + clickY + ")");
  } else {
    alert("Ouside shaded area at (" + clickX + ", " + clickY + ")");
  }
}

/* Click/touch function */
canvas.addEventListener(event, function(e){
  userAction(e, areaX, areaY, areaW, areaH, keyDown);
});

/* Keyboard functions */
function clickByKbd(e, x, y) {
  var key = e.keyCode;
  if (key == 32) {
      document.elementFromPoint(x, y).click();
      return false;
  }
}
document.documentElement.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
  keyDown = true;
  clickByKbd(e, window.innerWidth / 2, 100);
});
document.documentElement.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
  keyDown = false;
});
```

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  outline: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that once you use the key, which changes keyDown to true, nothing ever sets it back to false.

If you put a trace in your keyup function, it never fires (you were probably hoping that would reset the var...it doesn't).

If you want to keep this code as is and use a minimal fix, do this:

```
document.documentElement.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
  keyDown = true;
  clickByKbd(e, window.innerWidth / 2, 100);
  keyDown = false; // reset after firing the event. 
});
```

Note that now you can remove your keyup handler.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thanks!